# How to use @this and function.call together?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Given the following JS code, When calling `bar.fun` via `bar.fun.call(b, 'hi');` how can I tell the compiler that I want `this` to be an instance of `Banana`?

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Bar
 * @property {function(this:Foo, string):number} fun
 */


class Foo {
  constructor(){
   this.n = 1;
 };
}

class Banana extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.b = 2;
  };
}

const b = new Banana();

/** @type {Bar} */
const bar = {
  /**
   * @this {Banana}
   * @param {string} s
   * @return {number}
   */
  fun(s) {
    return this.n + this.b + s.length; //Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Foo'
  }
};
bar.fun.call(b,'hi');
```

Comment: First, if you are using TypeScript, you should define class properties before accessing them with `this.smth`. E.g. above the constructor for `Foo` you should write something like `public n: number;`. Please edit your code. Otherwise, remove `typescript` tag.

Comment: I'm not writing TS. I'm writing JS using JSDoc annotations and then compiling with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting definitions. In the definition of `Bar`, you say that the `this` has type `Foo`, and later you annotate `bar` as having type `Bar`, but give an incompatible type to `fun`. I think if you don't annotate `bar` and let its type be inferred, you'll get the behavior that you want.